# ServiceManager.getService returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

Im trying to develop an app that checks your device's security, and im working on a feature that checks if the pattern is visible (In the lock screen, if u have a pattern and it shows on the screen).

Some versions ago, you could check this in `Settings.Secure` with:

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_VISIBLE)
```

They changed it and now it is on a class called `LockPatternUtils`, and the method is called `isVisiblePatternEnabled`.

The only way to access this class is through reflection, but when I do it, it throws `InvocationTargetException` caused by `NullPointerException`.

I tried to debug but got "source code does not match byte code", so I checked the source code in Android Code Search, and it throws NullPointerException cause inside this method, they use `ServiceManager.getService("lock_settings")`, and that specific part of code returns null.

It says that getService returns "a reference to the service, or `null` if the service doesn't exist".

The thing is that this service DOES exist, as when I execute the adb command to check a list of services that are running on the emulator, it appears.

So, here is my question: **Is there anything that I'm missing?**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old query, but I hope this helps.

Even with reflection, only system apps are allowed to get the 'lock_settings' service. This makes sense as these are secure features.